# How to (dynamically) set the name of a JButton with Action constructor

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, action

alright so i'm trying to program a simple GUI-based calculator in Java, only covering integer arithmetics.

So far i only got the layout, now i'm trying to add functionality. The idea is to append button names into a JTextfield and eventually evaluate its content.

Anywhoo as you can see below i aleady added all buttons anonymously to the panel and i'm trying to figure out a way to keep it that way while adding the same event handler to all of them. I figured addActionListener won't work with "new JButton" cos that can't handle the void...

I know i could just instantiate all of them explicitly and use the addActionListener method on those, but that seems kinda messy.

So yeah, the question is: Can i title my JButtons with an Action constructor? If so, is it possible "parametrically"?

Or should i just go with un-anonymous Button objects?

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;

public class FunctionalCalculator extends JFrame {
    
    public FunctionalCalculator(){
        var panel=new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        var text=new JTextField();
        
        var writeAction=new AbstractAction(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                //write button label to textfield
            }
        };
        
        add(panel);
    
        var c=new GridBagConstraints();
        c.weightx=1.0;
        c.weighty=1.0;
        c.fill=GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        
        c.gridwidth=4;
        panel.add(text,c);
        
        c.gridwidth=1;
        c.gridy=1;  
        panel.add(new JButton(writeAction),c); //<- used to be "7"
        panel.add(new JButton("8"),c);
        panel.add(new JButton("9"),c);
        panel.add(new JButton("/"),c);
        
        c.gridx=0;
        c.gridy=2;
        panel.add(new JButton("4"),c);
        c.gridx=1;
        panel.add(new JButton("5"),c);
        c.gridx=2;
        panel.add(new JButton("6"),c);
        c.gridx=3;
        panel.add(new JButton("*"),c);
        
        
        c.gridx=0;
        c.gridy=3;
        panel.add(new JButton("1"),c);
        c.gridx=1;
        panel.add(new JButton("2"),c);
        c.gridx=2;
        panel.add(new JButton("3"),c);
        c.gridx=3;
        panel.add(new JButton("-"),c);
    
        
        c.gridx=0;
        c.gridy=4;
        panel.add(new JButton("0"),c);
        c.gridx=1;
        c.gridwidth=2;
        panel.add(new JButton("="),c);
        c.gridx=3;
        panel.add(new JButton("+"),c);


        setSize(400,250);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        }
    
    
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        new FunctionalCalculator().setTitle("Calculator");
    }
}
```

Thanks a big bunch in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "title" and "name". Do you mean the name of a variable? If so, then you're barking up the wrong tree. You could already do a lot by simply getting the actionCommand, obtained through the ActionListener's ActionEvent parameter that is passed into the actionPerformed method, also obtainable by calling `.getText()` on the JButton object. This is probably where you should start.

Comment: Just create a method that creates a new JButton with a name and adds an action listener to it in the method, then returns that button so that you can use it inline like `panel.add(createNewButtonWithListener("name"),c);` Or create a class that extends JButton with the functionality built in.

Comment: `Action` has a `NAME` property.  So, you should create a class which extends from `AbstractAction`, provide a constructor which allows you to pass the name/title you want to use, then use `putValue(NAME, name)` to apply it